# Rails with Mongo - Hash in an embedded object is saved in the parent on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, hash

I have a document type which embeds an array of field_value objects:

```
class Document
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_many :field_values do
    def find_by_field(field)
      where(field: field).first
    end
  end

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :field_values
end
```

And this is the nested type:

```
class FieldValue
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :field

  field :value, type: Hash
end
```

Creation works fine, but on update the value hashes for any modified fields in the field_values get stored in the document itself.

If only one field is modified, the hash is stored in the document in the database, and not updated in the embedded field_value. If I modify more than one i get: (the json in the error message is the value hash of the first field)

```
undefined method `push' for {"text"=>"the new value"}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

Here is a sample of the document_parameters:

```
"document"=>{
    "structure"=>"595d2ec70a94e122903abe6e", 
    "field_values_attributes"=>{
        "0"=>{"field"=>{"id"=>"595d2ec70a94e122903abe70"}, "value"=>{"text"=>"default B"}}, 
        "1"=>{"field"=>{"id"=>"595d2ec70a94e122903abe71"}, "value"=>{"text"=>"refault"}}, 
        "2"=>{"field"=>{"id"=>"595d2ec70a94e122903abe73"}, "value"=>{"text"=>"default"}},
        "3"=>{"field"=>{"id"=>"595d2ec70a94e122903abe74"}, "value"=>{"text"=>"refault"}}
    }
}
```

Update method for documents controller:

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @document.update(document_params)
        puts @document.inspect
        format.html { redirect_to @document, notice: 'Document was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @document }
      else
        @document.structure.populate(@document)
        @document.field_values = [FieldValue.new]

        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @document.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```